# Dyamically Added jQuery Returns Strange Result from Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I'm using a javascript bookmarklet to dynamically add jQuery to a webpage.  The bookmarklet is:

```
javascript:var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

When I run this against a sample site (say www.google.com), by opening the web inspector in Chrome I get:

```
>jQuery;
  ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

*---- run the bookmarklet ---*

```
>jQuery;
  function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
>jQuery('a');
  [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```

Why is an array of empty elements returned?  My expectation is that an array or jQuery object of DOM elements would be returned.

Comment: Possibly just a display issue, is that in the console? try `$('a').html('')` and see if all the header link text disappears.

Comment: Try this: `jQuery('a:first').html()` It's probably just look empty.

Comment: Which Chrome version are you using? Have you installed any devtools-related extension?

Comment: Don't forget to accept someone's answer (click the green arrow next to the answer), or at least give them a vote up (click the gray up arrow), for spending time to answer your question.

Comment: I meant green check mark, not green arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably only **looks** empty because there are too much elements.

Try this: `jQuery('a').hide()`. If you don't see any link anymore in the page, it works... **:-)**

Comment: `a:first` does not return a list of all anchors.

Comment: @RobW. I know, who said it will? He only want to check jQuery works for the page. anyway, it can be done with `.hide()`...

Comment: This might be a helpful pointer for debugging, but it suits better as a comment. The question is "Why is an array of empty elements returned?". I can't see how `jQuery('*').hide()` answers that question. jQuery is loaded, since it's originally `undefined`, and `function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}` after executing the bookmarklet snippet.

Comment: @RobW. O.K. changed to `jQuery('a').hide()` though hiding all the page is a lot cooler... **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Possibly just a display issue with the console. I verified working on my latest chrome by adding your code as a bookmark, and then hiding all the links on google.com.

Only thing I can think is you have not waited for the script/page to load. You could add some logs into the bookmarklet to ensure the script has loaded.

As a side note chrome/jquery seems to render the array with it's length (in the console) before populating the array. On this page open the dev tools and run `$('a')`. You will see ~ 170 commas before the the console shows the HtmlElement in the array.

Answer (score 0):

When I do exactly as you describe using your own bookmarklet, in the developer console of the latest stable version of Chrome I get an array of dom elements, as you expected to get. It looks like the abbreviated code below.

```
[
<a href=​"/​setprefs?prev=https:​/​/​www.google...">​Screen reader users,...</a>​
, 
<a onclick=​"...</a>​
, 
...
, 
<a id=​"cpNavLink" href=​"javascript:​void(0)​">​Change background image​</a>​
]
```

What I noticed though is that for a fraction of a second, I get an empty array like your example. Then a fraction of a second later that is filled in with the dom elements. I can almost see it being filled in element by element. So, my guess is that something is buggy with your Chrome or your console.